# youtube videos on web site is through iframe of embed tag

Tags: html, youtube

the best practice to post youtube videos on website is through using iframes or embed tag

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>
```

or

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

my question is which is best practice for posting videos on site......
and what are effects on performance using both of them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new style is the `<iframe>`. For more information [look here](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780&expand=UseOldEmbedCode#oldcode) with this notification:

`Please keep in mind, the mobile player cannot be embedded on external mobile sites.`

Comment: what will be the performance differences in both of them... cause i saw in some sites there most of them advice not to go for iframes...

Answer (score -1):

I think it is always safe to use embed tags. Use of iframe in websites is a source of vulnerabilities. iFrames opens up window for hackers. For embed tag, there is no major security issues being reported.

Embed tag is much more effective, as we can handle different situation more effectively, like is player not supported etc...

Comment: No, IFRAME in itself is not a security issue, issue is if some one (virus/hacker) has injected that IFRAME in your pages.

Comment: You realy think that Youtube infects your website by giving you iframe code to implement on your website??